Laravel Horizon not displaying a specific job at all?
So I have a job running and I can see it is running but only in the horizons log file.
2024-08-15 14:58:08 App\Jobs\Cache\UpdateDocument .................. RUNNING
2024-08-15 14:58:14 App\Jobs\Cache\UpdateDocument .......... 5,874.69ms DONE
2024-08-15 14:58:14 App\Jobs\Cache\UpdateDocument .................. RUNNING
2024-08-15 14:58:20 App\Jobs\Cache\UpdateDocument .......... 5,416.38ms DONE
2024-08-15 14:58:20 App\Jobs\Cache\UpdateDocument .................. RUNNING
2024-08-15 14:58:23 App\Jobs\Cache\UpdateDocument .......... 3,367.49ms DONE

The problem is, in Horizon, both the Pending jobs, Completed Jobs and Failed jobs are empty. The only place where I can see something is happening is on the dashboard.
Since this "UpdateDocument" is a brand new job, recently implelented by the dev. team, I am wondering if they have missed something from the code as if I execute something that requires the same queue, the task is added to the pending jobs list and I can clearly see it. So what are the requirements for a job to be displayed in Horizons Pending jobs?
